# How to call an alerady made Form with CodeNameOne with the code ligen clicking on a button

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

i want to call a form already designed with CodeNAmeOne and call it with

```
protected void onConnexion_Button1Action(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    TextField tf1 = findTextField(Display.getInstance().getCurrent());
    String email = tf1.getText();
    if(email.equals("client")){
        Form f;
        f.show();
    }
```

but didnt find how to call the form i want from the design i can get teh components but not the form please i need the answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
showForm("MyFormName");
```

This can be useful:

http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code.html